# Group by a Collection attribute using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object that contains a Collection of strings, let's say the languages that a person speaks.

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private List<String> languagesSpoken;

   // ...
}
```

Now, creating some instances like this...

```
Person p1 = new Person("Bob", 21, Arrays.asList("English", "French", "German"));
Person p2 = new Person("Alice", 33, Arrays.asList("English", "Chinese", "Spanish"));
Person p3 = new Person("Joe", 43, Arrays.asList("English", "Dutch", "Spanish", "German"));

//put them in list
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3);
```

... what I want to have is a `Map<String, List<Person>>`, for every language listing the persons that speak the language:

```
["English" -> [p1, p2, p3],
 "German"  -> [p1, p3],
 etc. ]
```

Of course this can be programmed easily in an imperative way, but how to do it the functional way with Java Streams? I have tried something like `people.stream.collect(groupingBy(Person::getLanguagesSpoken))` but that of course gives me a `Map<List<String>, List<Person>>`. All the examples I could find, are using `groupingBy` on Primitives or Strings.

Comment: Since you want to think "functionally", you can start by thinking about the properties of group by. A groupby can only generate *at most* as many elements as the input (if they are all in different "classes"). In your case the number of languages can easily be more than the number of people (in fact your example it's exactly this case). So it does not matter what arguments you give to the `groupingBy` collector, you need to do something to  your `List<Person>` so that it has at least a number of elements equal to the number of languages spoken. One possibility is Eran's answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can break the `Person` instances into pairs of language and `Person` (using `flatMap`) and then group them as required:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> langPersons =
    people.stream()
          .flatMap(p -> p.getLanguagesSpoken()
                         .stream()
                         .map(l -> new SimpleEntry<>(l,p)))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                         Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                            Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Streams and Lambda Expressions were added for readability right? (I have nothing against your perfect answer btw, just a comment on Streams and Lambda Expressions themselves..)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible to do without streams too, still using java-8 new features.

```
people.forEach(x -> {
        x.getLanguagesSpoken().forEach(lang -> {
            langPersons.computeIfAbsent(lang, ignoreMe -> new ArrayList<>()).add(x);
        });
});
```